# Reference Number changing automatically

Tags: cross-referencing

[image]

[image]

Why my reference number is changing automatically?
I want the reference number should be [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6QhE.jpg), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwTJS.png) and [3] ..
But when I give \cite{....} command and build it, reference number changes (marked by green)

Please help.

Comment: You have not shown enough detail to answer your question. Are you using bibtex, or biber to generate the references, or writing the bibliography by hand? There are two common numbering schemes: number references in order of first use, or to number in alphabetic order of author names. It is impossible to tell what you have specified here.

Comment: The point of using `\cite` is that you do not write an explicit `[1]` in the source.

Answer (score 2):

Your references seem to be in alphabetical order: first Metz, then Richter, then Shockley. Presumably there is another reference somewhere else in your text with an author name that comes alphabetically before Metz, which makes that one nr [1] and Metz is [2] and so on. Alphabetical order of references is very common, so you can just leave it as it is.

If you do want references in the order that they are cited then the approach depends on which method you use for citations.

If you use normal Bibtex without the `natbib` package then you can use `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}`. Don't forget to remove the current command that specifies the bibliography style, probably something like `\bibliographystyle{plain}`.

If you use the `natbib` package you can use `\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}` instead.

If you use Biblatex then it is `\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}`.

Note that in you code you currently have numbers written manually, like `[1]` in `\cite{metz2015international} [1]`. I assume you just put them in to clarify this question, in order to show which numbers you wanted. However, if this is not the case and you put them in your actual document as reference numbers, then you are not using the citation mechanism in the right way.

The idea in LaTeX is that you *never* put any numbers manually (not for citations, not for footnotes, not for section titles, not for figure captions, not for enumerated lists, etc. etc.) and LaTeX will automatically assign the numbers and change them when needed. When you use the `\cite` command the correct number is automatically added to the output, and you are not supposed to put an additional number yourself.

Which number is generated depends on the options that you set, so if you use `unsrt`, `unsrtnat` or `sorting=none` then the numbering is according to the order of appearance in the document, and if you use `plain`, `plainnat`, or some of the many other styles available, then the sorting is usually alphabetical by author (but other options are available as well, like sorting by year, or by publication title, etc.).

Comment: I have just put numeric number to keep track of my reference. I have also checked my citation after removing the manual numeric citation number.